# Has Adi Shankaracharya quoted Baudhayana Vritti in his commentary on Brahma Sutras?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, brahma-sutras

While reading biography of Ramanujacharya, I came to find that Baudhayana, who is known as Vrittikara, wrote a commentary on Vedavyasa's Brahma Sutra. In the time of Ramanujacharya, this work of Bodhayana is not easily available. He tried to get the copy of Bodhayana Vritti in whole country and finally he found that it's only available and preserved in the library at Kashmir. Ramanujacharya wrote Bhashya on Vedanta Sutra on the basis of (or taking the reference from) Bodhayana Vritti as described in the biography of Ramanujacharya.

Now I think that if it's very difficult to get Bodhayana Vritti in time of Ramanujacharya then it would be quite possible that it would be easily available in the time of Adi Shankaracharya. So, he might be aware about this work of Bodhayana and possibly he had quoted in his Bhashya on Brahma Sutra.

So, I want to know **whether Adi Shankaracharya has quoted Bodhayana Vritti in his Bhashya on Brahma Sutra? If yes, then I would more like to know whether he quoted as Purvapaksha (in disagreement) or as Siddhanti (in agreement)?**

Comment: As far as I know, Shankara does not take the name of Bodhayana anywhere in his sutra bhashya. He takes the name of Upavarsha. Vishishthadvaitins think Upavarsha is same as Bodhayana. But no one really knows for sure. These could be different people.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion Do the Shankaracharyas think Bodhayana and Upavarsha are different people?

Comment: @Ikshvaku I do not know the opinions of current shankaracharyas.

Comment: Here's some talk about it: https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/archives/advaita-l/2012-June/031995.html

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a problem of Sampradayas. This is summarized by WisdomLib here:

> It has already been shown that the Brahma-Sutras of Badarayana somehow
> gained prominence and popularity and as a result all the great
> Âcharyas have written commentaries on it. The oldest of the extant
> commentaries is by Sankara, the exponent of Monism. A Vritti by
> Upavarsha is mentioned by Sankara and Bhaskara and a Vritti by
> Bodhayana is referred to and often quoted by Ramanuja in his Sri
> Bhashya. **Sankara does not refer to Bodhayana. According to Vedanta
> Desika the two are one person. Unfortunately this work of Bodhayana is
> not available now.** Ramanuja quotes also from the Dramida Bhashya which
> evidently belongs to the Bhakti cult of Southern India. Sankara was
> followed by a host of commentators on these Sutras—Yadava Prakasha,
> Bhaskara, Vijnana Bikshu, Ramanuja, Nilakantha, Sripati, Nimbarka,
> Madhwa, Vallabha and Baladeva There are even some recent commentaries,
> though of not much value. All these try to maintain that their system
> is the one that Badarayana propounded through his Sutras.

Source: [https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62756.html#:~:text=It%20has%20already,through%20his%20Sutras](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62756.html#:%7E:text=It%20has%20already,through%20his%20Sutras).

We'll never know, but certain text-based lexical analyses from different commentaries *may* give us some hints regarding that.